# Counting state changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

i was wondering if it's possible to count the number of changes between a value in a record

for example i have the following data

```
| radio | name | state | timestamp           |
|-------|------|-------|---------------------|
| 1     | AP1  | down  | 2013-03-07 10:00:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | down  | 2013-03-07 10:15:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | up    | 2013-03-07 10:30:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | down  | 2013-03-07 10:45:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | pend  | 2013-03-07 11:00:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | pend  | 2013-03-07 11:15:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | pend  | 2013-03-07 11:30:00 |
| 1     | AP1  | pend  | 2013-03-07 11:45:00 |
```

I need to make a query that does the following trick

```
| name | S1     | S2     | S3       | S4         | (other time range) |
| AP1  | A      | A      | B        | A          | C                  |
                     \      /    \      /    \      /
                      DETECT      DETECT      DETECT    
                            \        \       / 
                             \------- \     /
                                       COUNT = 3 <-- this is the number i want
```

So far i'm stuck in SQL that is based on counts.

```sql
SELECT radio, name, state, COUNT(state) AS count FROM data
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2013-03-07 10:00:00' AND '2013-03-07 11:00:00'
GROUP BY radio, name, channel
```

The result will then be

```
| radio | name | state | count |
|-------|------|-------|-------|
| 1     | AP1  | down  | 3     |
| 1     | AP1  | up    | 1     |
| 1     | AP1  | pend  | 1     |
```

So the result now will be 3 rows aka 3 state change but then i realized this isn't true because this number
will only tell me the number of different state names, 3 in this case.

So my question is is this possible in SQL or do i need to pull the result set into a loop and detect the changes via a external script or a view.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: The mssql version is 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
with Changes as
(
  select name
    , stateChange = case when prev.state is null then 0
      when sc.state <> prev.state then 1
      else 0
      end
  from data sc
    outer apply
    (
      select top 1 prev.state
      from data prev
      where sc.timestamp > prev.timestamp
        and sc.name = prev.name
      order by prev.timestamp desc
    ) prev
)
select name, stateChanges = sum(stateChange)
from Changes
group by name
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32b5b/1).

Also, in your question, your data is a bit inconsistent; sometimes you're mentioning *AP1* and sometimes *AP2*. If the above query/fiddle is not sufficient please supply a larger dataset.

Comment: ah yes it's a "copy/paste typo" :) fixed it

Comment: also playing with this one and it seems i have some working stuff now :) doing some final tests and if it works i'll mark it as a solution

Answer (score 2):

You could use LAG() :

```
SELECT sq.RADIO,
  sq.NAME,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN sq.STATE != sq.PREV_STATE THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) CHG_COUNT
FROM
  (SELECT 
    td.RADIO,
    td.NAME,
    td.STATE,
    COALESCE(LAG(td.STATE,1) OVER(PARTITION BY td.RADIO, td.NAME ORDER BY td.TIMESTAMP ASC),td.STATE) PREV_STATE
  FROM DATA td) sq
GROUP BY sq.RADIO, 
  sq.NAME
```

Comment: Correct, I thought it was implemented in earlier versions. In this case Ian's suggestion is quite elegant.